# is there any way to make generic abstract mapper<K, V>in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have below class in my java code :

```
public abstract class DtoMapper< K, V > {

    public abstract T map(K input);

}
```

And above DtoMapper< K , V> i am using in below class:

```
@Component

public class RequestDtoMapper < TestA, TestB> extends DtoMapper < TestA, RequestDto, TestB> {

    private Object input;

    public RequestDtoMapper(TestA key,TestB key2){

        if(key instanceof TestA){
            input =  (TestA)key;
        }else
            input = (TestB) key2;
    }
}

@Override

  public RequestDto **map(Object input)** {

    //some code here
}
```

So is there any way to make this **input parameter of type `TestA` or `TestB` dynamically at runtime?**

Comment: Something like `public abstract class DtoMapper<T>`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before Answer a question here.

Comment: yes public abstract class DtoMapper<K,V>

Comment: `public abstract class DtoMapper<K, V>` should work, You can pass any class in `K(key)` and `V(value)`

Comment: It already *is* generic, and you already can pass any type - that's what your parameters in angle brackets are for

Comment: As @MichaelBerry has mentioned it is already generic. Please add more details if you mean something else.

Comment: Why is `K` ignored, and where is `T` supposed to come from?